# TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, sockets, tensorflow, keras

I am using threading method to make multiple client to one server. I am using a pretrained model with resnet50 to predict something.
My prediction code is

```
def prediction(array):
    array = np.array(array , dtype = np.float64)
    array = np.reshape(array, (1,224,224,3))
    #print(array.shape)
    a = preprocess_input(array)
    model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    features = model.predict(a)
    #print(features.shape)
    image = features.reshape(features.shape[0] , -1)
    #print(image.shape)
    loaded_model = keras.models.load_model('RESNET50.h5')
    y_predict = loaded_model.predict(image)
    if y_predict[0][0] > y_predict[0][1]:
        return "Non-Nude"
    else:
        return "Nude"
    K.clear_session()
```

and my server code is this

```
class ClientThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self,ip,port,sock):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.sock = sock
        print("New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port))

    def run(self):
        send_one_message(self.sock, self.ip)
        send_one_message(self.sock, self.port)
        data = recv_one_message(self.sock)
        #print("data recevied")
        res = prediction(data)
        send_one_message(self.sock, res)


TCP_IP = ''
TCP_PORT = 12001
tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
threads = []

while True:
    tcpsock.listen(5)
    print("Waiting for incoming connections...")
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpsock.accept()
    print('Got connection from ', (ip,port))
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port,conn)
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

It is able to connect multiple clients but it give fine prediction only for first client connected and for every another client it throws an error as
[image]

thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post error logs and code as text, not as pictures.

Comment: Okay edited. Thanks and sorry